# how to insert date value to oracle in php

Tags: php, oracle, date, phpexcel

I have a problem to enter a date value to oracle database using php. Before I enter into the table, I convert the value into a date but did not work. the result is always "1970-01-01", which should not that date.

my script below:

```
$kol[$n] = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($n, $row)->getValue();
$koldate = date('Y-m-d', $kol[$n]);
$sValues = "$sValues '".$koldate."'," ;
echo "$koldate";
```

If anyone can help?

Thank you.

Baskoro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An excel date/time is a serialized timestamp, the number of days since Jan 1st 1900 (or Jan 1st 1904 if using the Mac 1904 calendar).

If you use `getValue()` to read a value from a cell containing a date/time value, then you will get that raw timestamp.

You can convert that value to a unix timestamp or to a PHP DateTime object using the methods `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()` or `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()` respectively. Once converted, you can use PHP's normal date functions or DateTime methods (as appropriate) to convert the format to `Y-m-d`

```
$tmpDate = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($n, $row)->getValue();
$kol[$n] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($tmpDate);
$koldate = date('Y-m-d', $kol[$n]);
$sValues = "$sValues '".$koldate."'," ;
echo "$koldate";
```

Comment: Hi Mark, i still get error like this: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in D:\xampp\htdocs\Upload\uploadrainterface.php on line 67

Comment: So what's line 67 (and the few lines above it) in your code? Unless the value in the cell is a rich text object (and not a date at all) then you should never get an object back from a call to getValue(), just the float for the serialized Excel datetime value

Comment: here is the code: 
line 65  $tempDate = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($n, $row)->getValue();
line 66  $kol[$n] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($tempDate);
line 67  $koldate = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($kol[$n]));
line 68  $sValues = "$sValues '".$koldate."'," ;

Comment: If you use `ExcelToPHPObject()` you will get a PHP DateTime object back, and then you have to use the DateTime object's `format()` method to convert the DateTime object to a human-readable format..... if you want to use the `date()` function to make a `unix timestamp` human-readable, then you need to use `ExcelToPHP()` to convert the MS Excel serialized date/timestamp to a unix timestamp

Comment: I change it to ExcelToPhp() but the value is still "01-01-1970"

Comment: DON'T DO `$koldate = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($kol[$n]));`.... after the call to `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($tmpDate);`, `$kol[$n]` is NOT a date string, it's a unix timestamp, so trying to treat it as a string will generate a false result..... __read the code that I posted in my answer__, you won't see ___any___ use of `strtotime()` there at all

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `date()` must be a Unix timestamp. So unless `$kol[$n]` is already a Unix timestamp you will need to convert it to one before passing it to `date()`. You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this:

```
$koldate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($kol[$n]));
```

FYI, this assumes `$kol[$n]` is in [an acceptable date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Comment: It doesn't work. I take date from excel file. the date is 09/30/2013.

Comment: Works for me: https://eval.in/176926. Make sure `$kol[$n]` actually contains the value you think it contains.

Comment: It works fine if i change strtotime($kol[$n]) to strtotime('09/30/2013') manually.

Comment: Right, which means `$kol[$n]` doesn't contain the value you think it contains. You need to figure out why.

Comment: The value in the Excel file may ___look___ like a date, but is actually a floating point value (probably 41547.00) that is an Excel serialized datetime value, and it is the cell format masking that makes it look like a human-readable date

Comment: Yes Mark, you're right. When I change the date format in an excel file into a general format, which appears is 41547.